# can't sync certain characters with rsync

Tags: rsync

I have a few files in pdf format with the "/" character which they will not sync.
getting an error

> payment 2?28?17.pdf.FnILj5" failed: Invalid argument (22)

It appears the / is not recognized. If I change it manually to a . it will recognize and sync. any way to batch change those pdfs?

Comment: Do you have a '/' character in a filename? This is not a legal filename (all characters are allowed except '/' and null. If you are syncing from some other OS to Linux try renaming the source file.

Comment: Yea, you can't have a / in a file name, at least on Linux or Windows.  Did this come from a Mac or something?  Maybe it allows it.

Comment: @muclux, psusi, one of You could improve it a bit and post a comment as an answer in my humble opinion.  I don't think anything would be possible with the file which name is just not acceptable as it's rather a path than a name. Renaming seems like only possible solution.

Comment: I’m migrating to Linux from Mac..have a ton of PDFs which I saved the date as month/day/year.....is there a way to batch change?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you can't have a '/' character in a filename as this character is used for folders. So you have to rename the files before syncing them to a Linux file system.

I don't know about scripts in MacOS but there is certainly a possibility to rename all your files with a script (e.g. to month_day_year...). If you can't do it yourself you could find help in the [Super User](https://superuser.com/) community.